# null pointer exception found in java

Tags: java

```
private static Properties getProperties(File file)
    {
        InputStream in = null;
        try
        {
            in = new FileInputStream(file);
            return loadProperties(in);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (in != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    in.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click on the save button to save my configuration then I get null pointer exception. I tried to debug the code, In that time I have found the value of object **in** is null.  I do not understand why?

I have also checked that the path which I have pass as argument file is correct

Comment: What line does in = null?  Or is this function just returning null because of an exception that you are ignoring?

Comment: I have initialized reference variable to the null after starting the debugger then it first execute the try block first statement only in = new FileInputStream(file) after that value of in found null it go to the catch block.... I am new in  developemnt so could please help me to remove this error

Comment: Never silently swallow exceptions.

Comment: Please add the null stack trace and indicate which line in your code corresponds to the error line in the stack trace.

Comment: This looks like a textbook example of when to use try-with-resources btw

Answer (score 1):

I beileve there is only one reason the NPE happens -- it didn't find the file with the path you give.

> I have also checked that the path which I have pass as argument file is correct

Sometimes even you're thinking you provided a correct file path, depends on the directory hierarchy, program may refer tt relative path which may be different from the path you give.
Then you got **in = null**.

try [ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) instead of FileInputStream(), you can put your file under class path.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure that the `file` object is exists using `file.exists()`. If the file exist it will return `true`. If the `file` object is `null` it will also raise NullPointerException.